# On Error Goto doesn't work inside EventHandler subs

Tags: vba, error-handling

Lets assume this code:

Module1:

```
Sub main()

    Dim cl As New Class2
    On Error GoTo errorhandler1
        cl.DoWork
     On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

errorhandler1:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)

End Sub
```

Class1:

```
Event MyEvent()

Public Sub DoWork()
    RaiseEvent MyEvent
End Sub
```

Class2:

```
Private WithEvents cl As Class1

Private Sub cl_MyEvent()
    Call Err.Raise(123, , "ErrorInClass")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set cl = New Class1
End Sub

Public Sub DoWork()
    cl.DoWork
End Sub
```

I expect errorhandler1 to launch and MsgBox with err.Description to be shown.
But it throws me runtime error instead.

What I have to do to handle errors within EventHandlers routines?

Comment: for all event handlers you have to do an own error handling. Maybe this lession 26 about errorhandling and events handling is a good read [http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/Lesson26.htm]. To claify: Raising an event is different from calling a method. The call to the event's sub is separated. The sub will not return anything back to the method that raises the event.

Comment: @HolgerLeichsenring sadly this lesson has nothing about handling errors in eventhandlers. What do you mean by "for all event handlers you have to do an own error handling"? It seems that Err.Raise in EventHandler subroutine just can't be intercepted at all by error handler, isn't?

Comment: Didnt mention that detail, that the error handling in events is not different at all to "normal" methods. You have to the same. The sample in the answer does make sense to me. If you want to know if work has been done, you have to provide this information as a property or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193267.aspx#sectionSection10):

> If you use the Raise method of the Err object to raise an error, you
>   can force Visual Basic to search backward through the calls list for
>   an enabled error handler.

But in this case there is no enabled error handler.

Maybe you could inform the client of class2 that the work failed. Here because the client of class2 is a standard module you can't use events from class2, so maybe just a simple read-only property might help here?

> Module:

```
Sub main()
    cl.DoWork
    If Not cl.IsWorkOk Then MsgBox "Work failed..."
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

errorhandler1:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)

End Sub
```

> Class2:

```
Private m_isWorkOk As Boolean

Private Sub cl_MyEvent()
    On Error GoTo ErrMyEvent
    Call Err.Raise(123, , "ErrorInClass")
    m_isWorkOk = True
    Exit Sub
ErrMyEvent:
    m_isWorkOk = False
End Sub

Public Property Get IsWorkOk() As Boolean
    IsWorkOk = m_isWorkOk
End Property
```

Comment: not sure this is an answer to my original question, but a kind of acceptable workaround.

Comment: there is no enabled error handler ```backward through the calls list```. When the RaiseEvent is executed the calls list is interupted I gues. Therefore only possibility to catch the error is to add error handler in the event handler directly.

Answer (score 5):

This has just bitten me - you see in this simple C# code:

```csharp
try
{
    SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
catch
{
    // break here
}
```

If any handler of `SomeEvent` throws an exception, AFAIK a breakpoint in that `catch` block *would* be hit - and I was expecting VBA to do the same... and it doesn't.

By breaking in an event handler, and then inspecting the call stack, you can see that there's *something* slipping between the event source with the `RaiseEvent` call, and the event handler procedure:

[image: "Non-Basic Code" between the event source and the event handler]

I presume that `[<Non-Basic code>]` here would be the VBA runtime itself, dispatching the event to whatever object is listening for events on that particular event source instance: and this "man-in-the-middle" is quite likely why run-time errors aren't bubbling back up: the runtime is likely protecting itself and throwing an error here, regardless of whether the parent stack frame has an `On Error` statement.

You can see a hint of my work-around in that screenshot - add a new class module, call it `ErrorInfo`, and give it some useful members:

```
Option Explicit
Private Type TErrorInfo
    Number As Long
    Description As String
    Source As String
End Type
Private this As TErrorInfo

Public Property Get Number() As Long
    Number = this.Number
End Property

Public Property Get Description() As String
    Description = this.Description
End Property

Public Property Get Source() As String
    Source = this.Source
End Property

Public Property Get HasError() As Boolean
    HasError = this.Number <> 0
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As ErrorInfo
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Sub SetErrInfo(ByVal e As ErrObject)
    With e
        this.Number = .Number
        this.Description = .Description
        this.Source = .Source
    End With
End Sub
```

Now whenever you define an event, add a parameter to it:

```
Public Event Something(ByVal e As ErrorInfo)
```

When you *raise* that event, supply the instance, handle errors, inspect your `ErrorInfo` object, invoke `Err.Raise` accordingly, and you can handle *that* error normally, in the event-invoking scope you want to handle event-handler errors in:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    With New ErrorInfo
        RaiseEvent Something(.Self)
        If .HasError Then Err.Raise .Number, .Source, .Description
    End With
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
End sub
```

The event handler code simply needs to handle its errors (any run-time error in a handler is basically unhandled otherwise), and set the error state in the `ErrInfo` parameter:

```
Private Sub foo_Something(ByVal e As ErrorInfo)
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Err.Raise 5
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    e.SetErrInfo Err
End Sub
```

And bingo, now you can cleanly handle errors raised in an event handler, at the event source, without involving global variables or [losing the *actual* error information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30936553/1188513) (in my case, an error thrown in some 3rd-party API) to some useless (but arguably "good-enough" in most cases) "oops, didn't work" message.

#### Important caveat

As is the case with `Cancel` events, if an event has multiple handlers, then *which state* goes back to the event invocation site is, well, undefined - if only one handler throws an error, and the non-throwing handlers don't tamper with the `ErrorInfo` parameter, then in theory the invocation site gets the one error. The "fun" begins when two or more handlers throw an error.

In that case, the handlers need to verify what the state of the `ErrorInfo` is before they modify it.

Or, another solution could be to make the `ErrorInfo` class encapsulate an *array* of error information, and perhaps add indexers to the `Property Get` members - or whatever other mechanism you could think about, to "aggregate errors". Heck, you could even encapsulate a *collection* of `ErrorInfo` instances in an `AggregateErrorInfo` collection class, and make your "multiple-listeners event" use that in its signature instead.

Most of the time you only need a single handler though, so this wouldn't be a concern.