# Custom event raised by userform not bubbling error back to original calling procedure

Tags: vba, error-handling, event-handling

I might be missing something obvious, but why isn't the error bubbling up to the original calling procedure and being handled by ErrorHandler in this setup?

**Module1**

```
Public Sub Start()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    With New Class1
        .StartProgram
    End With
    
CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error found"
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

**Userform1** - with a single button

```
Public Event SomeEvent()

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    RaiseEvent SomeEvent
End Sub
```

**Class1**

```
Private WithEvents uf As UserForm1

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set uf = New UserForm1
End Sub

Public Sub StartProgram()
    uf.Show vbModal
End Sub

Private Sub uf_SomeEvent()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1 / 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, I get the same behavior. If I'm not misunderstanding anything this problem has already been discussed here: [On Error Goto doesn't work inside EventHandler subs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935147/on-error-goto-doesnt-work-inside-eventhandler-subs)

Comment: Voted to close this question as it seems that it has been covered in the linked dupe... but if you are awaiting an answer, feel free to comment here and I or someone else will gladly reopen.